# priorvalue is blank or --None-- update internal status "In-progress" workflow

Tags: workflow, formula, field-update

created workflow criteria is **created and everytime edited** but it's not working
if priorvalue of internal status is *blank* or *--None--* and record is not `isNew()` then update internal status picklist is "In-progress"

```
AND( 
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE( InternalStatus__c), " "), 
    OR(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE( InternalStatus__c), "--None--")), 
    NOT(ISNEW()) 
)
```

Comment: Use `ISBLANK(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(InternalStatus__c)))` to detect blank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
AND( 
    ISBLANK(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(InternalStatus__c))), 
    NOT(ISNEW()) 
)
```

Comment: Ah i did a cross post, was few mins late. +1!